# iMessage Extension: Get height of compact view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, imessage-extension

Is it possible to get the height of the compact view (red area in screenshot) of an iMessage Extension? Or is the height fixed? I couldn't find any information on the Apple Website.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MSMessagesAppViewController` subclass has its view in this space. Look at its `frame`.